# Is there a way to not save an object but the fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a new UserProfile model. Code below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

This code is getting triggered by the signal and working but it saves a UserProfile object, not the individual fields (image attached)[image]. What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to write a custom Manager? Or do I need to override the save() method somehow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to share how you are creating the User instances

Comment: Where exactly do you fill in the individual fields?

Comment: Furthermore thiks only shows the `__str__` of the `UserProfile` objects, since you do not include any `location`, `bio`, etc. it will of course not display that information.

Comment: Does **UserProfile object (2)** is your problem?

Comment: User instance is being created by DRF (Django Rest Framework). The default way.

The fields are not being inserted because I am not asking them for that information at the time of sign up (which is when User model fires post_save). This will be filled later on. 

I understand that it will show a blank field in bio and location but my question is, when I click on the User table, I see columns of information (username etc.) but when I open the UserProfile (which is being created by a signal, it shows "UserProfile object (2)", which is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by creating a custom User model that extends AbstractUser.